# Receiving Semicha in Jerusalem

Tags: semicha

Which well known English speaking (preferably) Rov in Jerusalem would give Semicha despite not having learnt by him/his Kollel etc? Rabbanut Semicha is a bit too bureaucratic for me.

I would say in lieu of the Semicha of Rav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg ZTL now that I am unfortunately unable to get from him.

Comment: I'm not sure if Rav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg zatzal spoke English. If you would have been fine with him, I heard rumours his son in-law will start giving smicha in lieu of his father in-law.

Comment: @Robev who is Rav Goldberg’s Tz”l son in law?

Comment: I have a couple of friends who did all the studying in London and then went to Israel to Rav Moshe Sternbach shlita to get their semicha

Answer (score -1):

Please see attached photo of Rabbis that give Semicha. I cannot confirm if they speak English.

But hopefully this should be stepping stone to finding out what info you need. [image]

Comment: This is an outdated document. I'm not sure why it includes people who were not alive at that time, but even more have since passed away.

Comment: I checked their website and they still use this list, I don’t know why maybe those who already hold semicha by them many years ago. I only know that Rav Berkovitz is still alive, I don’t know about the rest of the rabbonim. Can someone filter and post answer for the Israel, Jerusalem who are still alive?

Comment: I know Rav Rav Moshe Lazerus and Rav Berl Wein are alive. And you're right that it makes sense for their list to include those who passed away, but it doesn't make sense for this question.

Comment: Rav Berkovitz speaks English, I know someone who learnt by him.

Comment: He does speak English, but I don't know if he gives smicha to random people who he doesn't know. I feel this answer could use a lot of work.

Comment: I’m just surmising, perhaps the test rabbi will need a reference from a known Rabbi attesting that the person is shomrei Torah and Mitzvos. If in doubt give him a call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118759/discussion-between-daniel-ross-and-robev).